# checksum link calls up wrong form

Tags: profile, checksum, unsubscribe, opt-out

I am using WordPress 5.4 and CiviCRM Version 5.18.4. I am trying to include an "unsubscribe" link to put at the bottom of NON-bulk emails (including those sent by CiviRules).

I have created a Profile containing the email address and the "do not email" field.  It appears in my list of profiles as ID=31.

I create an email template, and at the bottom of the email I put a link to:
[http://mydomain.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=31&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}](http://mydomain.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=31&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&id=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

Correct?

I send a test email using that template, to a contact with Contact id=61.  The link in the email looks like:
https://mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=31&id=61&cs=12345678987654321

Looks great, yes?

I click on that link and get directed to
https://mydoimain.com/edit-your-info/?reset=1&gid=31&id=61&cs=12345678987654321
where "edit-your-info" is (roughly) the name of a DIFFERENT profile, one with profile ID=16.

In fact, browsing to https://mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=31 seems to ALWAYS take me to the "edit-your-info" page, no matter what number I set gid equal to, or even if I leave the "gid=N" out entirely.

Obviously I am making some silly mistake.  Any ideas what?

Comment: do you have any redirects?

Comment: Good question.  Nope, none in place.